# Why do input method files not compile or load normally?

Tags: emacs

I was fishing around in emacs-24.3/leim/quail looking at input method files.  For example

http://pastebin.com/iCTMsstL

is the file for cyrillic.  It doesn't byte compile or load, with the error

```
load-with-code-conversion: Invalid read syntax: "] in a list"
```

Are these files not valid lisp code?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've somehow used the wrong encoding for that file.

For example, lines 60 of your pastebin is

```
("1" ?,Lp(B)
```

But line 60 of emacs-24.3/leim/quail/cyrillic.el is

```
("1" ?№)
```

And so on. The file should evaluate successfully (say, with `eval-buffer`) once this problem is addressed (it does for me).

Comment: Thanks.  Agreed, it looks suspicious.  What encoding is Emacs choosing for your file?  Mine chooses utf8, which seems like a good choice in general, even for cyrillic.

Comment: Hmm, I get `iso-2022-7bit-unix` - which is not what I was expecting. You might try opening cyrillic.el in an `emacs -Q` to see if there is some setting that affects which coding system is selected for that file.